# QGIS 2.6.0 Atlas Export to multiple output files fails; RESOLVED

Tags: windows-7, qgis-2.6

QGIS version 2.6.0, date 01/05/2014 
OS Windows 7 Pro 64-bit

STEP 2 listed below notes resolution - Output should use field name(s) only (not 'attribute') to generate an atlas with multiple output files.

Description

When exporting Atlas features with Output to multiple files (i.e., 'Single file export when possible' checked OFF) and using either the Atlas export menu or the Atlas Preview export menu, Select Folder, the export then creates a single page file of the current atlas feature with the name of the Selected Folder and repeatedly overwrites this file as 
each atlas feature is exported. Reproduced for both pdf and images (jpg, png).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a set of features for Atlas generation
2. Export file name set to be based on one of the attribute fields - THIS WAS THE ISSUE. Simply using the field name(s) for Output file name generates the desired result.
3. Select Folder
4. Export

Expected behavior:
This feature worked fine for me in mid-November 2014, creating a folder of multiple output files of one page for each feature. i can report a bug if it appears to be one, but because it worked previously wanted to see if anyone had experienced this and resolved it.

Comment: I cannot confirm that behaviour using the exact same system configuration as you. Atlas exports without any problem. Notice that I have tested using 2.6.0 but there is a 2.6.1 update already.

Comment: Thanks for testing; have now reproduced the issue on two different machines (both same system config), and have updated to 2.6.1; same issue. Thought this might indicate issue with project or atlas composer code, but starting fresh on both did not resolve. Logged QGIS bug report.

Comment: It might be data related. Have you tried with different data? in different format and in a new project?

Comment: @ Alexandre Neto - RESOLVED. issue was trying to use 'attribute' for output file name; simply entering the filed names generates the desired result. Humble apologies.

Comment: dan please add your resolution as an answer (and also feel free to Accept it as correct). Following the Q&A pattern of the site makes it easier to understand the problem and solution. Thanks!